# Prove that the additive groups $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are not isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, group-isomorphism

Is my proof below correct? What specific property of rationals did I exploit in my proof? It looks like the property I exploited is the following: Given any positive rational, I can always write it as sum of arbitrary number of positive rationals, whereas given any positive integer I cannot write it as a sum of arbitrary number of positive integers. Has it got to do with the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field?

---

> **Problem** Prove that the additive groups $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are not isomorphic.

**Solution** Let there exist an isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$. Now consider the element $1_{\mathbb{Q}}$. We then have $\phi(1_{\mathbb{Q}}) = z \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $\phi$ has to be a bijection, $z$ cannot be zero, since $\phi(0) = 0$.

Now consider the element $\left(\dfrac1{z+1}\right)_{\mathbb{Q}}$. We now have $$z = \phi(1_{\mathbb{Q}}) = \phi\left(\underbrace{\left(\dfrac1{z+1}\right)_{\mathbb{Q}} + \left(\dfrac1{z+1}\right)_{\mathbb{Q}} + \cdots + \left(\dfrac1{z+1}\right)_{\mathbb{Q}}}_{z+1 \text{ times }} \right) = (z+1) \phi\left(\left(\dfrac1{z+1}\right)_{\mathbb{Q}}\right)$$
However, there is no element in $y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $(z+1)y = z$.

---

**First update**

Actually I realize that I complicated it unnecessarily. Instead, we can do like this. Since $\phi$ is an isomorphism, we have $\phi(q_{\mathbb{Q}}) = 1_{\mathbb{Z}}$ for some $q \in Q$. However, $$\phi(q) = \phi(q/2+q/2) = 2\phi(q/2)$$ And there is no $y \in Z$, such that $2y=1$. Hence, $\phi(q/2)$ remains unmapped.

---

Thanks

Comment: If $z=-1$? You have to exclude this case.

Comment: But for the case $\;z=-1\;$ it looks fine. Deal with the particular case separatedly.

Comment: Have you thought that additive group of $\mathbb Q$ is not cyclic

Comment: You may unconsciously assume that $z>0$. You get problems not only with $z=-1$, but also with $z=-2$. - I rather suggest you have a look at $m:=\phi(\frac12\phi^{-1}(1))\in\mathbb Z$, which should have the property $m+m=1$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Actually, I realized my mistake. I have now added an update. Can you tell me if this works?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proving that additive groups are isomorphic $(n\mathbb{Z}$ and $m\mathbb{Z}$) or not ($\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383190/proving-that-additive-groups-are-isomorphic-n-mathbbz-and-m-mathbbz-or)

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635770/mathbbz-is-not-isomorphic-to-mathbbq

Comment: That's correct,but it's ridiculously complicated. You really need to try and find the simplest counterexamples and proofs,it's a bad habit that can get you into trouble down the line.

Answer (score 40):

Another proof is as follows:

Suppose that $\phi : \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is an isomorphism. Then there is some $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\phi(r) = 1_{\mathbb{Z}}$.

So what is $\phi(r/2)$? We would have to have

$$
1_{\mathbb{Z}} = \phi(r) = \phi\big(2(r/2)\big) = 2\phi(r/2)
$$

or equivalently that $\phi(r/2) = \frac{1}{2}$. But this is not in $\mathbb{Z}$, so there can be no such morphism.

Comment: ... Which I see you just added to the question.

Comment: Thanks. I added this to the proof about a minute back. So is my proof a proof by contradiction?

Comment: Yes. You are assuming the existence of an object, and then deriving a conclusion that is at odds with that very object's existence.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. This is helpful.

Comment: @Leslie: You can also do a direct proof as follows. Let $\phi:\Bbb Q\to\Bbb Z$ be any homomorphism. Since there is no $z\in\Bbb Z$ such that $2z=1_{\Bbb Z},$ then for all $q\in\Bbb Q,$ we have $1_{\Bbb Z}\ne 2\phi(q)=\phi(2q).$ In particular, then, since $\frac r2\in\Bbb Q$ for all $r\in\Bbb Q$ and $r=2\left(\frac r2\right),$ then for all $r\in\Bbb Q$ we have $\phi(r)\ne1_{\Bbb Z}.$ Hence, $\phi$ is not surjective. Since $\phi:\Bbb Q\to\Bbb Z$ was an arbitrary homomorphism, then no homomorphism $\phi:\Bbb Q\to\Bbb Z$ is surjective, and so $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb Z$ are not isomorphic.

Comment: @CameronBuie Yes. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. How have you assumed in the last part that $\mathbb{1}_\mathbb{Z}$ is $1$? We are given that the groups under consideration are the *additive* groups, $\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}$. Isn't the $\mathbb{1}_\mathbb{Z}$ = $\mathbb{1}_\mathbb{Q}$ = 0 in this case.

Comment: Also, since the groups are additive, we have in this case the homomorphism condition $\phi(xy) = \phi(x)\phi(y)$ becomes $\phi(x + y) = \phi(x) + \phi(y)$, which allows us to conclude that $\phi(0) = 0$. Clearly under any homomorphism/isomorphism, we have $\phi(\mathbb{1}_\mathbb{G}) = \mathbb{1}_\mathbb{H}$, if $\phi : G \longrightarrow H$ is a homomorphism/isomorphism. Doesn't this also show that $r$ must be zero, and dividing zero by another number will still give the equation $\phi(0) = 0$.

Comment: @SimonRose See above.

Comment: @CameronBuie See above.

Comment: @Junaid: "Clearly under any homomorphism [$\phi:\Bbb G\to\Bbb H$], $\phi(1_{\Bbb G})=1_{\Bbb H}$." This is false. Consider for example $\Bbb G=\Bbb H=\Bbb Z,$ and the group isomorphism $\phi(x)=-x.$ Now, as one may conclude readily (from an argument similar to that outlined in my comment), the only group homomorphism $\Bbb Q\to\Bbb Z$ is the map $q\mapsto0.$ Is that what you're getting at?

Comment: @CameronBuie, maybe u meant something else but its definitely true that every homonorphism maps 1 -> 1 where 1 is the identity element in the respective groups. In fact, the example you gave confirms this as you are explicitly sending every element of Q to 1 (since 0 is the identity in Z).

Comment: @H_1317: Oh! I see what happened now. I will address the rest in a comment to Junaid.

Comment: @JunaidAftab: H_1317's comment lets me see where we were not on the same page. By $1_{\Bbb Z},$ I didn't mean the (additive) identity of $\Bbb Z,$ just the copy of the number $1$ that lives in $\Bbb Z,$ as opposed to the one that lives in $\Bbb Q.$ This many years later, I'm not sure why I felt that distinction was an important one to make.... Apologies for the confusion!

Answer (score 23):

Note that the additive group $\mathbb Z = \langle 1\rangle$ is generated by one element (and hence is cyclic), whereas $\mathbb Q$ is not cyclic, nor can it be finitely generated. In any case, being cyclic is a structural property of groups that is preserved by any isomorphism.

---

Just to make sure you understand that the additive group $\mathbb Q$ is not cyclic, we want to show $\mathbb Q$ is't generated by some element $\dfrac ab$, where $a, b \in \mathbb Z$ i.e., that there is no element $\dfrac ab\in \mathbb Q$ such that $\left\langle \dfrac ab \right\rangle = \mathbb Q$.  We want to show that it is not the case that every rational number is an integral multiple of $\dfrac ab$.

Suppose $\left\langle\dfrac ab \right\rangle = \mathbb Q$.

Observe that, under this assumption $\dfrac a{2b} \in \mathbb Q$, being a rational number, should then be an integral multiple of $\dfrac ab$,  which it clearly isn't; it is $\dfrac 12 \dfrac ab.$

Hence the assumption that $\mathbb Q$ is generated by $\dfrac ab$ cannot be true. Since $\dfrac ab$ is arbitrary, this shows $\mathbb Q$ is not generated by any single element in $\mathbb Q,$ i.e., $\mathbb Q$ is not cyclic.

Comment: The OP asked what property is being exploited.

Comment: @DeitrichBurde  This has been dealt with.

Comment: All right! It took me a while to remember what we did 5 years ago:)

Comment: I hadn't seen your comment, until the answer was recently upvoted, and I was like, Dah! why did I  not add that?; it would certainly make a better answer!  So, @DeitrichBurde, it was more of a "closure" notification, though I missed expressing my  "thanks" for pointing that out!

Answer (score 16):

Suppose there is an isomorphism $f:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Q$.

Let $a=f(1)$; then $f(\mathbb Z)=\{na,n \in\mathbb Z\} \ne \mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 9):

The group $\mathbb Q$ has the property that for any $x\in \mathbb Q$ and any integer $n\geq 1$, there exists $y\in \mathbb Q$ such that $n\cdot y=x$. In other words, $\mathbb Q$ is *divisible*. The group $\mathbb Z$ is *not* divisible, so since "being divisible" is invariant under isomorphism, $\mathbb Z\not\cong\mathbb Q$.

**Edit:** This proof exploits the fact that $\mathbb Q$ is a field in the following way (best seen after generalization). Let $A$ be an integral domain(not a field) with field of fractions $K$. A similar proof shows that if $M$ is *any* finitely generated $A$-module and $V$ is *any* finite-dimensional $K$-vector space, then $M\not\cong V$ as $A$-modules. The reason is that because $K$ is a field, $V$ is a divisible $A$-module, and $M$ is not. (The fact that finitely generated $A$-modules are not divisible is probably most easily seen by localizing at a maximal ideal and using Nakayama's lemma).

Comment: I didn't say it is easier - it is just different approach. That said, the fact that divisibility is invariant under isomorphism requires no thought to check - just do the obvious thing.

Comment: So essentially I exploited the fact that I can divide in rationals. So in essence I exploited the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field. Is my understanding right?

Comment: Is it more or is it less?

Comment: Ok. I do not know about integral domains, modules, Nakayama lemma etc. Hopefully, when I read those I will be able to appreciate your answer. I am still in the first chapter of Dummit and Foote. Thanks for the answer though. Good to know that the key property being exploited is $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field.