# Does a map exist for these groups to be isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory

The groups $(G, \cdot)$ and $(H, \odot)$ are isomorphic if a bijective map $\phi : G \rightarrow H$ exists, where $\phi (a \cdot b) = \phi(a) \odot \phi(b)$.  I cannot find a map $\phi$ that does this when $G = \mathbb Z$ and $H = \mathbb Q$, and when $G = U(20)$ and $H = U(24) $. The group $U(n)$ uses the multiplication operation and comprises of all integers relatively prime to n.  For example, $U(24) = \left\{ 1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23\right\}$    Is it correct to say that these groups are not isomorphic?

I thought of showing that U(20) and U(24) are of different order, but they have the same order.  Thus, this proof failed.

Comment: $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Q$ are not isomorphic. Nor are $U(20)$ and $U(24)$. But "I cannot find a map that does this" is not a proof...

Comment: Note, your stated definition of isomorphic is incorrect. Not only should $\phi$ preserve the group operation, but it also needs to be bijective. In the definition you give $\phi$ is just a homomorphism.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I have added bijective into my definition of isomorphic.  Also, how would I prove that two groups are not isomorphic?  Thanks

Comment: This should help with the first one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620551/prove-that-the-additive-groups-mathbbz-and-mathbbq-are-not-isomorphic

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you couldn't find a map is evidence that they *might* not be isomorphic, but that isn't a proof.

Here's an idea. You know that the integers with addition are a cyclic group. You know that an isomorphism maps a cyclic group to a cyclic group. If you can show the rationals under addition are not cyclic, you'll have your proof.

Comment: Why does an isomorphism map a cyclic to a cyclic?

Comment: It's not too hard to prove. Consider any element g^k. What will this map to under your isomorphism?