# Proving that the additive groups $\mathbb{Z}$ and$\mathbb{Q}$ are not isomorphic.

Tags: proof-verification

I'm asking this question to review the second answer, the one with 7 votes, posted in response to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620551/prove-that-the-additive-groups-mathbbz-and-mathbbq-are-not-isomorphic/). Since the thread is very old, I'm not sure if I'll get a response to the comment I posted.

Isn't the proof given in the answer incorrect? The last part of the proof assumes that $\mathbb{1}_\mathbb{Z} = 1$. Isn't this wrong since in the *additive* group, $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$, isn't the identity element, $\mathbb{1}_\mathbb{Z}$, equal to $0$?

Comment: Maybe you should link to the answer itself rather than the question, or just give the author's name.

Comment: The notation can be rather deceptive. Of all 1s mentioned in the proof, **none** is assumed to be the group identity.

Comment: I think here $1_\mathbb{Z}$ is not referring to the additive identity for $\mathbb{Z}$.  It looks like it's just $1$, but considered as an element of $\mathbb{Z}$ rather than as an element of $\mathbb{Q}$, for clarity.

Comment: @JairTaylor Yes, I thought so, too. See the comment I posted below. I guess I'll remove this question as it's wasn't very constructive either way. Also, I wasn't sure how to link the specific question within the post.

Answer (score 1):

He doesn't use the fact that $1_{\Bbb Z}$ is the identity element in $\Bbb Z$ because is clearly false. He uses the fact that an isomorphism is a bijection, then if there exists an isomorphism $\phi$ between $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb Z$, then there necessarily exists a rational $r\in\Bbb Q$ such that $\phi(r)=1_{\Bbb Z}$. Finally he uses the homomorphism property to get an absurdness.

Comment: Oh, the last $1$ doesn't have $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subscript, so I assumed this the number one. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @JunaidAftab There's no need for such a subscript anyway

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes. The fact that the proof used it till the last point led me to infer that the substitution $\mathbb{1}_\mathbb{Z} = 1$ has been made.