# Show that $\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $n\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, group-isomorphism

Could someone please see whether my solution is okay? I cannot find any duplicates, since my search engine on here doesn't let me search well.

> Show that $\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $n\mathbb{Z}$ for $n\neq 0$.

Define $\phi:\Bbb{Z}\to n\Bbb{Z}$ by $\phi(r)=nr$ for some fixed $n\in \Bbb{Z}^{*}$.

Well-defined: If $r=s$ for $r,s\in \Bbb{Z}$, then $\phi(r)=nr=ns=\phi(s)$.

Operationing-preserving: $\phi(r+s)=n(r+s)=nr+ns$ (integers distribute over addition) $=\phi(r)+\phi(s)$

Injective: If $\phi(r)=\phi(s)$, then $nr=ns$ or $r=s$ since $n\neq 0$.

Surjective: $\phi$ is onto iff for all $nr\in n\Bbb{Z}$, there exists an $r\in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $\phi(r)=nr$. By construction of $\phi$, it is onto.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving that additive groups are isomorphic $(n\mathbb{Z}$ and $m\mathbb{Z}$) or not ($\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383190/proving-that-additive-groups-are-isomorphic-n-mathbbz-and-m-mathbbz-or)

Comment: The answers show that $n\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $m\mathbb{Z}$. Take $m=1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct, with one odd comment: your "well-definedness" step is unnecessary.

---

Since this can be a subtle point, let me say a bit about what's going on here. "Well-definedness" shows up in the following situation:

> Suppose we have a set $E$, and elements of $E$ correspond to equivalence classes under $\sim$ of some set $S$. Then we can define a function from $E$ by defining a function from $S$ instead ... **provided that** we separately show that $\sim$-equivalent elements of $S$ get sent to the same object.

I've deliberately written that informally. More precisely, but also maybe less intuitively:

> Suppose $E=S/\sim$. Then if $f:S\rightarrow X$ has the property that $s_1\sim s_2\implies f(s_1)=f(s_2)$, then $f$ "induces" a function $\hat{f}: E\rightarrow X$ given by $\hat{f}([s])=f(s)$ for all $s\in S$.

Let's consider an example. We can think of a rational number as an equivalence class of elements of $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_{\not=0}$, given by $$(a, b)\sim (c, d)\iff ad=bc.$$ For example, $(1, 2)\sim (2, 4)$ - that is, ${1\over 2}={2\over 4}$. Now consider the following:

> Let $f:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ be defined by $$f({a\over b})=a+b.$$

*(Here I suggestively write "${x\over y}$" instead of "$(x, y)$" for simplicity.)* This is of course nonsense. What's really going on is:

- I've defined a function $f:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_{\not=0}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ given by $f(a, b)=a+b$.
- I've then implicitly claimed, without justification, that $f$ "respects $\sim$" - that is, $(a, b)\sim (c, d)\implies f(a, b)=f(c, d)$.

This second step of course is false: as observed above, $(1, 2)\sim (2, 4)$, but I leave it as an exercise to show that $1+2\not=2+4$.

Now what does this have to do with **your** situation? Well, nothing! That's because you've defined a function from $\mathbb{Z}$ directly; you're not defining a function on a set which $\mathbb{Z}$ is a quotient of, and then implicitly claiming that that function respects the equivalence relation. So there's no "well-definedness" claim here that needs to be proved.

*(OK, there **is** actually a claim that needs to be proved here: you need to prove that the map $r\mapsto nr$ is actually a function from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $n\mathbb{Z}$, that is, each $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ gets sent to some $y\in n\mathbb{Z}$. This is essentially trivial - obviously $nr\in n\mathbb{Z}$, as long as $r\in\mathbb{Z}$ - but is necessary to prove in the sense of providing a **completely rigorous** proof. But that's not what you're talking about when you say "well-definedness," and also might not be something you need to explicitly write in this particular exercise.)*

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time in writing out a very clear explanation of well-definedness. I learned a lot about it from your comment! Your last paragraph is basically what my instructor wants us to do with any given mapping, and I think she would like us to do this by showing well-definedness, since this is an elementary algebra course, I guess...

Answer (score 1):

As Serge Lang wrote at the beginning of his *Algebra* book:

> Let $A$ be a set with an equivalence relation, let $E$ be an equivalence class of elements of $A$. We sometimes try to define a map of the equivalence classes into some set $B$. To define such a map $f$ on the class $E$, we sometimes first give its value on an element $x \in E$ (called a representative of $E$), and then show that it is independent of the choice of representative $x \in E$. In that case we say that $f$ is **well defined**.

This is the context in which "well defined" comes up. If your equivalence relation is just "$=$" then checking if something is *well* defined is the same as checking if it is *defined*. After you *define* something, hopefully, you already know whether or not that thing is *defined*.

Also $\mathbb{Z}^* = \{-1,1\}$ is the set of invertible integers. Only in a field $F$ do you have $F^* = F \setminus \{0\}$.

The rest is good.